# Serializing XML into POCO and then into JSON string

Tags: c#, xml-parsing, json.net

I have the following XML and I need to serialize it into a POCO and then deserialize it to JSON.
Here's the XML:

```
<PAC xmlns="https://mynamespace.com">
  <Creds>
    <AID>1019766</AID>
    <AToken>290D56096864849B</AToken>
    <AcID>01234</AcID>
  </Creds>
  <App>
    <AppID>133</AppID>
    <AppName>XML</AppName>
    <AppVer>1.1.1</AppVer>
  </App>
  <PAcct>
    <PAcctType>0</PAcctType>
    <PAcctRefNum>000001</PAcctRefNum>
  </PAcct>
  <CD>
    <CN>4445_220007</CN>
    <EM>12</EM>
    <EY>25</EY>
    <C3></C3>
  </CD>
</PAC>
```

Here's the object(s) that I'm attempting to populate from the XML and then deserialize to JSON. CCS and PAC are base objects derived from TObjects, which contains all the other objects.

```
[XmlRoot("CCS", Namespace = "https://mynamespace.com")]
public partial class CCS : TObjects
{
    public TTypeID TTypeID { get; } = TTypeID.CCS; // Enum for TTypes
}
[XmlRoot("PAC", Namespace = "https://mynamespace.com")]
public partial class PAC : TObjects
{
    public TTypeID TTypeID { get; } = TTypeID.PAC; // Enum for TTypes
}
public partial class TObjects
{
    public Creds? Creds { get; set; }
    public App? App { get; set; }
    public PAcct? PAcct { get; set; }
    public CD? CD { get; set; }
}
public partial class App
{
    public int? AppID { get; set; }
    public string? AppName { get; set; }
    public string? AppVer { get; set; }
}
public partial class Creds
{
    public int? AID { get; set; }
    public string? AToken { get; set; }
    public string? AcID { get; set; }
}
public partial class PAcct
{
    public int? PAcctID { get; set; }
    public string? PAcctType { get; set; }
    public string? PAcctRefNum { get; set; }
}
public partial class CD
{
    public string? T1 { get; set; }
    public string? T2 { get; set; }
    public string? CN { get; set; }
    public CL? CL { get; set; } // CL is Enum
    public int? EM { get; set; }
    public int? EY { get; set; }
    public int? C3 { get; set; }
}
```

I've been using Newtonsoft's SerilizeXmlNode() with this code; this code removes the namespace before doing the serialization.

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml(System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(xmlString.Trim(), @"(xmlns:?[^=]*=[""][^""]*[""])", "",
                        System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.Multiline));
string jsonText = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(xmlDoc.FirstChild, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
```

It produces a valid Json string but the integers are all strings and it does not recognize empty values in the XML.

I need to also be able to pass in other XML and serialize to their corresponding objects derived from TObjects, like CCS above, and then deserialize to Json.

How can I convert the above XML into this Json string and ignore the empty values and formatted with the classname as the root?

```
{
  "PAC": {
    "Creds": {
      "AID": 1019766,
      "AToken": "290D56096864849B",
      "AcID": "01234"
    },
    "App": {
      "AppID": "133",
      "AppName": "XML",
      "AppVer": "1.1.1"
    },
    "PAcct": {
      "PAcctType": "0",
      "PAcctRefNum": "000001"
    },
    "Card": {
      "CN": "4445_220007",
      "EM": 12,
      "EY": 25,
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: *I have the following XML and I need to serialize it into a POCO and then deserialize it to JSON* -- did you mean ***deserialize** into a POCO* and ***serialize** it to JSON*?  Or if not, what do you mean by "serialize it into a POCO"?

Comment: Also, if you have a data model POCO anyway, why are you converting directly from XML to JSON using `JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode`?  Why not just serialize the POCO to JSON with `JsonConvert.SerializeObject()`?

Comment: We use the JSON in an intermediate step, then convert it back to XML in a later step.

Comment: @dbc, I suppose you could be correct but standard XML serialization didn't work here to correctly create our POCO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is there a reason to use class as interstitial step?

option without interstitial class

```
string xml = "<PAC xmlns=\"https://mynamespace.com\"><Creds><AID>1019766</AID><AToken>290D56096864849B</AToken><AcID>01234</AcID></Creds><App><AppID>133</AppID><AppName>XML</AppName><AppVer>1.1.1</AppVer></App><PAcct><PAcctType>0</PAcctType><PAcctRefNum>000001</PAcctRefNum></PAcct><CD><CN>4445_220007</CN><EM>12</EM><EY>25</EY><C3/></CD></PAC>";
     
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml(xml);
    string jsonText = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc).Dump();
```

result:

```
{
    "PAC": {
        "@xmlns": "https://mynamespace.com",
        "Creds": {
            "AID": "1019766",
            "AToken": "290D56096864849B",
            "AcID": "01234"
        },
        "App": {
            "AppID": "133",
            "AppName": "XML",
            "AppVer": "1.1.1"
        },
        "PAcct": {
            "PAcctType": "0",
            "PAcctRefNum": "000001"
        },
        "CD": {
            "CN": "4445_220007",
            "EM": "12",
            "EY": "25",
            "C3": null
        }
    }
}
```

update full example to convert. dont need namespaces

```
void Main()
{
    string xml = "<PAC xmlns=\"https://mynamespace.com\"><Creds><AID>1019766</AID><AToken>290D56096864849B</AToken><AcID>01234</AcID></Creds><App><AppID>133</AppID><AppName>XML</AppName><AppVer>1.1.1</AppVer></App><PAcct><PAcctType>0</PAcctType><PAcctRefNum>000001</PAcctRefNum></PAcct><CD><CN>4445_220007</CN><EM>12</EM><EY>25</EY><C3/></CD></PAC>";

    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml(xml);
    string jsonText = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
    var r = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(jsonText);
    JsonConvert.SerializeObject(r, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented).Dump();
}

    public class App
    {
        public int AppID { get; set; }
        public string AppName { get; set; }
        public string AppVer { get; set; }
    }

    public class CD
    {
        public string CN { get; set; }
        public int EM { get; set; }
        public int EY { get; set; }
        public object C3 { get; set; }
    }

    public class Creds
    {
        public int AID { get; set; }
        public string AToken { get; set; }
        public string AcID { get; set; }
    }

    public class PAC
    {
        [JsonProperty("@xmlns")]
        public string xmlns { get; set; }
        public Creds Creds { get; set; }
        public App App { get; set; }
        public PAcct PAcct { get; set; }
        public CD CD { get; set; }
    }


    public class PAcct
{
    public int PAcctType { get; set; }
    public string PAcctRefNum { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    
    public PAC PAC { get; set; }
}
```

and result would be

```
{
  "PAC": {
    "@xmlns": "https://mynamespace.com",
    "Creds": {
      "AID": 1019766,
      "AToken": "290D56096864849B",
      "AcID": "01234"
    },
    "App": {
      "AppID": 133,
      "AppName": "XML",
      "AppVer": "1.1.1"
    },
    "PAcct": {
      "PAcctType": 0,
      "PAcctRefNum": "000001"
    },
    "CD": {
      "CN": "4445_220007",
      "EM": 12,
      "EY": 25,
      "C3": null
    }
  }
}
```